# Instant payments options in Android and iOS app

Tags: google-play, app-store, stripe-payments, braintree

I have payoneer account and i'd like to receive payments from app into this account.

Payments are not for physical goods. They are more like app content-unblockers.

Let's focus on Android and Google Play distribution case.
I suppose, payoneer is not designed for processing quick small payments, right?

I need these:

1. App should be able to set price according to misc factors.
2. Payments should be instant without credit card entering - i guess it called "Payments from Google Wallet". E.g. if i (app user) have google account and i have payment method in Google Play, then i do not need to enter my credit card number again.
3. Payments should be possible independently of user location (country)

So, can I use, say, Braintree to process payments with those requirements?
Will it violate any kind of Google Play policies (the fact, that i'm processing payments not through Google)?

The same questions about iOS

Answer (score 0):

**For Android** : You can use third party payment seamless/non-seamless as long as their sdk supports Android platform. Google doesn't stop you from choosing any payment service.

**For iOS :** : It's million dollar question. Always refer to latest app store review guidelines https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies

You can use third party payment gateway in iOS if you are selling physical goods/services outside of the app. For any in-app purchases you must use IAP.

For any in-app purchases if you use other purhasing mechanisms **your app will be rejected**.

**Refer to section 3.1.1** 
If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP.